# qTranslate-X WP redirects to last selected language when typing URL without encoded language

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, qtranslate-x

I am using the qTranslate-X plugin in my Wordpress site. Everything works perfect for me but I found a problem. I have set Spanish as the default language, and the Catalan and English as the other language options.

If I rewrite the URL without the encoded language in the browser, having my page in English I expect to be sent to the default language of the web which is Spanish. But instead it remains in English.

What can I do to fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, qTranslate-X looks at both HTTP referrer and a cookie `qtrans_front_language` to try and figure out the language of the user's session if it's not deducible from the request URL.